# C++ function calling

Tags: c++

I have a task:

Fix wrong calls with `::`, delete unfixable constructions

```
int x = 4;

class A{
    int x;
public:
    A(int n = 1);
    virtual int f(int a=0, int b=0);
};
class B{
    int x;
public:
    B(int n = 2);
    int f(int a = 0);


};

class C: public A, public B{
    int x;
public:
    C(int n=3);
    int f(int a, int b=0);
    int g(A *p);
};

A * p; C c;
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    p = &c;
    x = c.g(p);
    x = c.f(); // wrong , no candidate , x=c.B::f()
    x = c.f(x);// C::f(int,int)
    x = c.f(x,1);// C::f(int,int)
    x = p->f();// C::f(int,int)
    x= p->f(x);// C::f(int,int)
    x = p->f(x,1); // C::f(int, int)


    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain these situations:

```
x = c.f(); // wrong , no candidate , x=c.B::f()
x = c.f(x);// C::f(int,int)
x = p->f();// C::f(int,int)
```

Where can I find function selection algorithm?

Comment: By 'task' do you mean 'homework'..?

Comment: overriding non virtual functions is not nice

Comment: it's one of possible tasks on my exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overload resolution is not applied across different class scopes (§7.4). In particular, ambiguities
between functions from different base classes are not resolved based on argument types.

(Stroustrup, The C++ Programming Language, 15.2.2)

Thus, compiler searches method by name first in "this" class, then recoursively in base classes regardless of wheather default values exist

```
x = c.f(); // wrong arguments number for C::f
x = c.f(x);// C::f(int,int) // it's clear
```

As of the last case `x = p->f();// C::f(int,int)`. It's a virtual function call. since `p` is a pointer of type `A*`, compiler check if `p->f()` corresponds to signature of A::f() and assigns default values to parameters. Compiler doesn't know which class the pointed object belongs to. At runtime virtual function call with all arguments defined "redirected" to actual implementation, in your case this is `A::f`

Comment: x = c.f(): firstly compiler searches by name, it will find C::f(int, int). But prototype isn't suitable( cannot be called without arguments) and there will be an error. Right?

Comment: i tried msvc compiler and got `Error 1 error C2660: 'C::f' : function does not take 0 arguments`

Comment: i have got same results with gcc. So i can conclude, that compiler stops searching on the first function with appropriate name.

Answer (score 0):

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

for the resolution.

Comment: I think the ♦ moderators should answer this...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thanks in advance for showing me errors. Kinda sorta newbie here.

Comment: Oh no, haha sorry about that, it was an attempt at humor (diamond moderators and diamond problem, see?) -- I didn't actually mean that they should be answering these questions! Sorry about that!

Comment: @Mehrdad: lol'd. Seing the diamond i thought that my browser went mad :)